# Validation in TaxonomyWebTaggingControl

Tags: taxonomy, term-store, term

I have control:

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl ID="myWebTaggingControl"
IsMulti="False" IsDisplayPickerButton="True"
ContainerId="mycontenerID" runat="server">
</Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl>
```

In code behind I set properties:

```
 myWebTaggingControl.SSPList = myTerm.TermStore.Id.ToString();
 myWebTaggingControl.TermSetList = myTerm.TermSet.Id.ToString();
 myWebTaggingControl.AnchorId = myTerm.Id;
```

I know that when we set AnchorId, then only children of this term will have valid value.
But is there a possibility to set this control, to term in anchorId will has also valid value and could be selectable?